# Header() redirection not to localhost/ but to an otehr website

Tags: php, redirect, header, localhost

**Hello, I want to make a panel so that we can change the redirection link of the page**,

in the header(); .
I want that the `header($result);`  redirect to `"amazon.com"` the official site (for example) and not http://localhost/amazon.com

```
($result which is amazon.com obviously)
```

**Is it possible ?**

I have already tried with javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = '<?php echo $result; ?>';
</script>
```

But it also returns me

```
"http://localhost/amazon.com"
```

**And here is the php code**

```
  header("Location: .$result");
  exit;
```

**Thanks in advance for your help**

Comment: the site address is not amazon.com but `https://amazon.com`

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is missing the scheme (`https://` or `http://`) or the marker to indicate that it is a scheme-relative URL (`//`).

`amazon.com` is therefore treated as a *relative path* and not as a hostname.

You need `https://amazon.com`